# How to setting scale in X axis?

Tags: javascript, charts

I try make some chart battery, but I have some trouble with interval in time. I have some code  like this

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ["2018-04-26 00:10:00", "2018-04-26 00:15:00", "2018-04-26 01:10:00", "2018-04-26 01:40:00", "2018-04-26 01:5:00", "2018-04-26 01:55:00", "2018-04-26 02:10:00"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                data: [11.2, 11.6, 12.1, 12.1, 12.2, 12.4, 12.4],
            }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
```

I don't know how to set interval 30 minute. If someone have some idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: interval of 30 mintues in js: `30 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: No, what I mean is how to set scale in X axis like 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00 from data like in code